# How can i obtain an Sql Language name from a .Net Culture

Tags: .net, sql-server, localization, full-text-search

Hello i'm using SQL server full-text search. when i use the FreeText predicate it need the language as parameter, but sql parameters name is different from .net culture names. So my question is How can i obtain an Sql Language name from a .Net Culture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LCID in the [SYS.SYSLANGUAGES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190303.aspx) view of SQL Server is the same Windows Locale ID returned by the [CultureInfo.LCID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.lcid.aspx) property in .NET. You can use this LCID as the `language_term` in your [FREETEXT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) search.